# View methods not getting called in a Tab bar controller

Tags: uiview, methods

i have created a VIEW BASED APPLICATIOn.
in that i am creating a tab bar with 4 view COntrollers.
So now the problem is that when i switch between different view controllers ,
the view methods like View will appear/disappear are not getting called .
But if i make a Tabbar based application ,they are getting called. 
Can anybody explain it , please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call

`[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in your `viewWillAppear` method first.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"testing..");
}
```